# Green's functions of Stokes flow?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, reference-request

In mathematics, a [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) is a type of function used to solve inhomogeneous differential equations subject to specific initial conditions or boundary conditions. A [fundamental solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) for a linear partial differential operator L is a formulation in the language of distribution theory of the older idea of a Green's function.

> In C. POZRIKIDIS's *Boundary Integral
>   and Singularity Methods for Linearized
>   Viscous Flow*,
>
> The Green's functions of Stokes flow
>   represent solutions of the continuity
>   equation $\nabla\cdot {\bf u}=0$ and the
>   singularly forced Stokes equation
>   $$-\nabla P+\mu
> \nabla^2{\bf u}+{\bf g}\delta({\bf x-x_0})=0 $$
>
> where ${\bf g}$ is an arbitrary constant,
>   ${\bf x_0}$ is an arbitrary point, and
>   $\delta$ is the three-dimensional
>   delta function. Introducing the Green's function ${\bf G}$, we write the solution  of (2.1.1) 
>   in the form
>   $$u_i({\bf x})=\frac{1}{8\pi\mu}G_{ij}({\bf x,x_0})g_j$$

I am confused with the Green's function in this text.

Here are my **questions**:

1. Is $P({\bf x})$ supposed to be the unknown
   in the [Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow#Stokes_equations-):

   $$ \begin{align}
   -\nabla P+\mu \nabla^2 u+\rho b&=0\\
   \nabla \cdot u &=0
   \end{align}
   $$
2. What does the Green's function mean here? (Is it "with respect to" $u$?)  <s>Why is it of that strange form?</s> Why is the solution of this kind of form?
3. <s>How can one get $\frac{1}{8\pi\mu}$?</s>What is the relation between ${\bf G}$ and $G_{ij}$? As I understand, $G_{ij}$ are the components and ${\bf G}:{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}^3$. Then one should write:
   $${\bf G}({\bf x})=\begin{bmatrix}
   G_1({\bf x})\\ G_2({\bf x})\\ G_3({\bf x})\end{bmatrix}$$
   where $G_i:{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$. What is $G_{ij}$?
4. What's the Green's function in the most general case?

Comment: Yes, p is the pressure in the Stokes equation. Yes, the Green's function given here is for representing the velocity. Why is its form strange, and what is "the most general case"?

Comment: @Michael Renardy: Thanks for the comment. Actually I don't understand how can one get $\frac{1}{8\pi\mu}$ in the solution formula.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of how you define $G_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved this question to [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42714/9464) a month ago. This is indeed the problem I got from the research, though it may not very appropriate here.

@Willie Wong gave a very nice [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42714/greens-functions-of-stokes-flow/50398#50398) to the question. Instead of closing or deleting the question, I think it's worth putting the link here.